# Error while using Jstree plugin in a firefox extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, jstree

I am using jstree in filrefox extension but cannot make it work.
It falls with error `$("#tree").jstree` is not a function.
But jstree does add some stuff to page's dom , like : `<div id="vakata-contextmenu">`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

have you made sure that you have included the jstree file and that too before you make use of the jstree api.

i.e
script include should precede $("#tree").jstree

Comment: Yes, absolutely!  I have additional check . When page is loaded completely I run the code bellow binded to button click event
Alert(jQuery().jstree) and get "indefined". 


All works fine when my code is inside common html page but then I put it inside extension it falls. I need somehow figure out why it falls…